# How to create a directory with dirsync in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, synchronization

I am trying to synchronize 2 directory, source and destination.
The destination doesn't exist, so I get the error

```
ValueError: Error: Target directory /mnt/sda1/backup_001/directory2828_bkp20220524 does not exist. (Try the -c or --create option to create it).
```

How can I pass the argument create to dirsync?

That's my code

```
from dirsync import sync

source_name='directory2828_bkp20220524'
source_path = '/home/micky/'+source_name

target_path = '/mnt/backup_001/'+source_name
sync(source_path, target_path, 'sync', verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is not clear, but suggests this solution.

For me it works.

https://github.com/tkhyn/dirsync

```
from dirsync import sync

source_name='directory2828_bkp20220524'
source_path = '/home/micky/'+source_name

target_path = '/mnt/backup_001/'+source_name
sync(source_path, target_path, 'sync', verbose=True, create=True)
```

In the documentation you can find this example about the config file.

https://github.com/tkhyn/dirsync

```
[defaults]
action = sync
create = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial off topic.
In the command line the command is this.

```
dirsync sourcedir targetdir --create
```